# How to append _thumb to all media uploaded and media that is already uploaded to my wordpress blog

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image

I was hoping to get some help on this one. I am looking to have appended to all images and media that get applied to a post via the upload tool in WordPress _thumb to the src of the media object.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this SO [wordpress-3-0-media-uploader-alters-my-image-filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124033/wordpress-3-0-media-uploader-alters-my-image-filename).

You could modify it something like;

```
function my_upload_prefix( $filename, $filename_raw ) {
    if( "_thumb" != substr($filename_raw, 0, 6) )
        $filename = "_thumb" . $filename;

    return $filename;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'my_upload_prefix', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks let me implment this and get back to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to do this on the front-end, a simple solution would be something like the following:

Assuming something like:

```
  <img src='image1.png'>
  <img src='image2.png'>
```

jQuery as follows:

```
var $allImages = $('img');

$allImages.each( function() {
    var curUrl = $(this).attr('src');
    var newUrl = '_thumbs/' + curUrl;
    $(this).attr('src',newUrl);
})
```

Would result in the following HTML:

```
 <img src='thumbs_/image1.png'>
 <img src='thumbs_/image2.png'>
```

And finally a working example at jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BTRax/7/

If you were trying to do this on the backend in PHP well then someone else will need to chime in :)

Comment: ThanX HurnsMobile... I was hoping for smething on the backend.